# Smallest subgroup generated by a set in a constructive way

Tags: group-theory

Given the group $G$ and the set $E$ contained in $G$, one way to define the subgroup $H<G$ and generated by the set $E$ is by setting $H:=EE^{-1}=\{e_1,e_2....e_n:n\in N, e_i \in E \cup E^{-1} \} $, where $E^{-1}= \{g\in G:g^{-1}\in E \}.$

I need to show that $EE^{-1}$ is the smallest subgroup containing $E$. Of course one can prove the existance of the smallest subgroup containg $E$ by taking the intersections of all subgroups containg $E$, but it is not what is asked here.

I have already tried by letting out one element $g$ and its inverse $g^{-1}$ such that $\{g,  g^{-1}\}\notin E$ and then tried to figure out if the new set, which is smaller than $EE^{-1}$, is a subgroup, i.e. a group. Unfortunately i could't come to a conclusion.

Can somebody give me some hint how to prove this following the way i am suggesting or some other way. Thanks.

Comment: Show that $H$ is a subgroup and show that any subgroup containing $E$ must contain $H$.

Comment: Hint: Since $E \subset G$ and $E^{-1} \subset G$, and $G$ is closed under products, you know that $EE^{-1} \subset G$.

Comment: Thats the point. I can show that H is a subgroup. To show that any subgroup containing $E$ must contain $H$, i would need to pick an element of $H$ and prove that it is contained in the subgroup. But i can eventually say that such an element is the product of elements belonging to $E^{-1}$ and not $E$. Will this matter ?

Comment: Briefly, the answer to your next to last question is NO. Look at the definition of $H$ again. It will be helpful to rewrite the definition of $H$ as $H:=EE^{−1}=\{x_1x_2....x_n:n \in N, x_i \in E \cup E^{−1} \}$

Answer (score 0):

You have defined $H = EE^{-1} $ and proved that $H$ is a subgroup. But if $K$ is another subgroup which contains $E$ then $K$ must also contain $E^{-1}$ and thus also $EE^{-1}=H$. I.e., $H$ is contained in all subgroups containing $E$; it is the smallest subgroup containing $E$. So you have already proved your proposition in the way you wanted to prove by proving that $H$ is a subgroup.